# How to call another (Refresh Token) API in Angular Interceptor?

Tags: angular, http, interceptor, angular-http-interceptors

I wanted to fetch new access token before making api request.
This token will append to previous api call in interceptor.
So how to make another api call in angular interceptor?

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import {
  HttpRequest,
  HttpHandler,
  HttpEvent,
  HttpInterceptor
} from '@angular/common/http';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable()
export class TokenInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() {}

  intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
// To do for validating token 
    request = request.clone({
        setHeaders: {
            Authorization: 'Bearer '+ localStorage.getItem('access_token')
        }
    });
    return next.handle(request);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular interceptor provides a way to call another api call before making actual api call.
Before proceeding further you need to import following

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { catchError, switchMap, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```

In above **tap** is being used to get response of intermediate call where as **switchMap** is used for calling **actual api call**.

So, it has following steps to do job.

1. you need to intercept actual api call
2. make http get api call for **fetching new access token**
3. parse response of above api **access token** in local variable or store in **localstorage**
4. clone actual api call request with latest **access token**
5. return the request

so, the code would look like below.

```
 constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  intercept(request: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return this.http.get(`https://<fetch access token URL>`, {observe: 'response'}).pipe(
      tap(response => {
        localStorage.setItem("access_token", response.headers.get('access_token'));
      }),
      switchMap(() => {
        request = request.clone({
          setHeaders: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('access_token')}`
          }
        });
        return next.handle(request);
      })
    );
});
```